# full height map in bootstrap 4 row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make this map go full height inside a Bootstrap4 column.

I have tried adding h-100 to the containing row  but I ended up with scroll bars at the bottom of the map, and about the bottom 10% of the page missing.

[image]

The relevant code for the layout is :

```
   <div class="row h-100">
    <div id="leftPanel" class="col-sm-2">
        <table id="tasklist" class="table table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>District</th>
                    <th>Activity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>12/12/19 08:00</td>
                    <td>ACD</td>
                    <td><a href="#">3F schools</a></td>
                    </a>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>13/12/19 19:30</td>
                    <td>WMD</td>
                    <td><a href="#">3T Burbank St</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="viewDiv" class="col-sm-10">
    </div>
 </div>
```

In the fiddle it changes again, so that the row is only as high as the number of rows in the left col div.

[Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/bigalnz/L5918bha/3/)

I would like to know how to get this map to take up the whole right col, but without ending up with scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add height property value like this:

```
height: calc(100vh - 56px);
```

56px is your topbar height and it is needed to subtract it from map height.

Comment: Well spotted sir :)

Comment: @t3x4r sorry, add that as a style to just the row, or?

Comment: @t3x4r on chome this results in the window "shimmying"

Comment: @AlGrant yeah, I saw that but just was hoped that is due to fiddle, not browser.

Answer (score -1):

1. I have added `container-fluid` for full width.
2. Add class `col-md-3` for left panel and `col-md-9` for map view
3. Set `height=700px` of `#viewDiv`. I have tried `height:100%` but it didn't worked it gets only pixels.

   ```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Map</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">

     <div class="row">
       <div id="leftPanel" class="col-md-3">
           <table id="tasklist" class="table table-sm">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Time</th>
                       <th>Area</th>
                       <th>Activity</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <tr>
                       <td>12/12/19 08:00</td>
                       <td>CD</td>
                       <td><a href="#">schools</a></td>
                       </a>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>13/12/19 19:30</td>
                       <td>MD</td>
                       <td><a href="#">Burbank St</a></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>13/12/19 21:00</td>
                       <td>CM</td>
                       <td><a href="#">Westfield</a></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>15/12/19 15:30</td>
                       <td>CM</td>
                       <td><a href="#">Langiola</a></td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
           </table>
       </div>

     <style>
      #viewDiv{ height:700px; }
     </style>
     <div id="viewDiv" class="col-md-9"></div>

     </div><!--end row-->

   </div><!--end container-->
   ```